# How to use a Variable Name which was Obtained at Run-Time

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, resources

All, to provide a on-the-fly mechanism for debugging an application in different languages I am using the required resource string (in a foreign language) to display the English equivalent at run-time should the user require it. This is done using

```
public static string GetMessage(string messageKey)
{
    CultureInfo culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    if (!culture.DisplayName.Contains("English"))
    {
        string fileName = "MessageStrings.resx";
        string appDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        fileName = Path.Combine(appDir, fileName);
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            // Get the English error message.
            using (ResXResourceReader resxReader = new ResXResourceReader(fileName))
            {
                foreach (DictionaryEntry e in resxReader)
                    if (e.Key.ToString().CompareNoCase(messageKey) == 0)
                        return e.Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Where `GetName` is defined as

```
public static string GetName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

I usually display localised messages in my application like

```
Utils.ErrMsg(MessageStrings.SomeMessage);
```

or

```
Utils.ErrMsg(String.Format(MessageStrings.SomeMessage, param1, param2));
```

Now I can display the relevent English message from my app running in a different culture using

```
Utils.ErrMsg(Utils.GetMessage(
    Utils.GetName(() => MessageStrings.ErrCellAllocStatZeroTotal)) ?? 
        MessageStrings.ErrCellAllocStatZeroTotal);
```

I want to avoid having to use a lambda expression in the call to `GetName` and the use of `null` from `GetMessage` and using `??`, how can I achieve this [if at all possible]?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How come you don't just return `messageKey` (the original value of it, not the overwritten version with the return value of `GetName`) instead of null from `Utils.GetMessage`? I must be missing something here so please enlighten me :)

Comment: I have had to edit the question as I was slightly ahead of myself. I can pass in the `MessageString` instance like I was doing or the reflection returns the local variable name in `GetMessage`. I now have two problems - avoid the lambda in the call and not having to use the null coalescing operator! Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not fully understand your code, but if you just want to access the properties of an object dynamically, try this (you have to replace [Object] and "PropertyName" with your specific values):

```
// get the property from object
PropertyInfo Property = [Object].GetType().GetProperty("PropertyName");

// get the value
int value = (int)Property.GetValue([Object], null);
```